# Judging self adjusting clutch reserve

Tags: clutch, opel, astra

I was told that the position of the protruding adjustment springs (indicated in red on the picture) can indicate the thickness of the remaining clutch lining.

Is that true and can somebody estimate the remaining clutch lining based on this pictures?

As a layman I am tempted to think that the position of the springs is proportionally to the remaining thickness, indicating about 1/3 reserve.

The car is an Opel Astra H with about 140KKM.

[image]
[image]